# open a ubuntu terminal and run terminal command like"`./executable -x -y`" form java code

Tags: java, linux

How to open a ubuntu terminal and run terminal command like"`./executable -x -y`" form java code? or how to launch ubuntu terminal from java program?

Comment: Do you specifically want the terminal window?  If so you will probably want to launch it with an argument which specifies an initial command to run.  Otherwise, you can more efficiently just launch the command directly.

Comment: did the answer help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux does not provide any single "terminal" command. It depends on which GUI is present (i.e. whether KDE, or Gnome, etc). However, try calling the term "xterm" which is present in many linux distros. Since Ubuntu is debian based, which in itself is gnome based, you should be good.

```
String cmd= "/usr/bin/xterm"; //the xterm might not be in that path. so figure that out.
Runtime runtym = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process prcssing = runtym.exec(cmd);
```

Hope this helps.